# How to upload a file using Ajax request in rails 2.3

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-2, jquery-1.4

I have a rails 2.3 application.

I am using Ajax request to submit the form content. In my form, I have a provision to upload files.

Issue with the form is, if I added a file to the form and submitted the form content, I am getting an error "Error: NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO: Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object Source" in "jquery-1.4.4.min.js" file and the form is submitting normally without using ajax request. But, the form is submitting form content using Ajax when there is no file selected to upload.

Can anyone please tell me how to upload file using Ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my above mentioned requirement at the following url. Hope it may help some one.

http://priyanka-railsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2011/11/allow-ajax-upload.html